# How to group the pattern in regex?

Tags: regex, python-2.7

```
str="status 2xx"
str="status 2xx,3xx"
str="status 2xx,3xx,4xx"
str="status blahblahblah"   # should not match this

import re
if re.match('status\s+(\dxx)',str):
    print "TRUE"  # This matches only first condition.
```

How do i get all those numbers (`2xx or 3xx or 4xx or all`), which are present after the text status ?
or Is there some other way to extract those sequences ?

can we handle in regex something like ([2xx | 3xx | 4xx]) ? This may not be correct, but someone help me here.

Comment: @Gurman : In your example, third case has only 2 patterns. and can i extract all those sequences in a single group ?

Comment: Thanks for downvoting. But is question incorrect or is it un-answerable ?

Comment: your question could be more clear.

what do you mean (2xx or 3xx or 4xx or all)?

Comment: @CalvinTaylor Thanks for responding, xx means xx only.no further numbers. 2xx,3xx,4xx , That's what i'm stressing as the pattern !!! Hope you got it.

Answer (score 1):

One option uses a regex to extract the CSV data, followed by a string split on comma to get a list of separate values.

```
str = "status 123,456    555 789"
m = re.search('^status\s+([0-9]+(?:(?:\s+|,)[0-9]+)*)$', str)

if m:
    nums = m.group(1)
    vals = filter(None, re.split("[, ]+", nums))
else:
    vals = list()

print vals
```

**Output:**

```
['123', '456', '555', '789']
```

## Demo

Comment: You are right, but very simplest way. Can we handle that in regular expression ? .* stands for anything. What if sequences are not present ? it still matches, right ?

Comment: @DieselKumar I think my answer is a simple way.  If your input data be something very different than what you showed above, then you should have included it.  How can I guess as to what your source data is?

Comment: @Diesel I updated my answer, which now returns a list of numbers only if the string matches your pattern, otherwise it returns empty list.

Comment: it matches for the string what you have given, not the one asked. pattern is 2xx,3xx etc. This doesn't work for that.

Comment: @DieselKumar, could be there input string `str="status 1x 2xx,3xx,4xx 5x 6x,7xy"` ?

Comment: So are you saying the separator could be comma or space?  Is your above comment the _full_ extent of the input, or do you plan on changing your question again later?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest : No, no string like this str="status 1x 2xx,3xx,4xx 5x 6x,7xy". All possibilities mentioned above.

Comment: @DieselKumar I have made another update.  Further changes to your question could draw downvotes.

Comment: why would my question get downvotes further ? what's wrong in that ?

Comment: can you test your snippet with test strings posted in above question ?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen : any luck ?